Proving $E[Y],E[X] = \infty$ given their conditionals are Poisson distributed
Let:
$$X \mid Y = y \sim \text{Poi}(a+y)$$
$$Y \mid X = x \sim \text{Poi}(a+x)$$
for some $a >0$.
Are $E[X],E[Y] = \infty$ ?
I tried:
$$E[X] = E[E[X\mid Y]]$$
which , with the symmetry of the conditionals , gives
$$ E[X] = a + E[Y]  $$
$$ E[Y] = a + E[X]  $$
implying $a=0$ , which seems wrong...
Is there a way to get the expectations without finding the joint distribution ?

If $a\ne 0,$ then your assumptions must be false. // When expectations are infinite or undefined, then "implying $a=0$" is invalid: you can't subtract off infinite or undefined quantities in an equation!  Your question, then, comes down to whether there possibly can exist a pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ whose joint distribution has the assumed properties.

Think of constructing a Gibbs sampler and finding the steady-state expected values.  Start with $x_0 = y_0 = 0$, then $\mathrm{E}x_1 = a, \mathrm{E}y_1 = 2a, \mathrm{E}x_2 = 3a\dots$.   Conclusions?
